# Not able to generate coverage report using jacoco plugin for test cases written using jmockit library

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, jmockit

I have unit test cases written using jmockit(version:1.44) library in my application. I am able to run the test cases using maven surefire plugin and generate coverage reports using below dependency-

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${project.basedir}/repo/org/jmockit/1.44/jmockit-1.44.jar
                </argLine>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, I want to integrate coverage report with sonar qube and started using jacoco plugin instead of surefire.
But I am getting the exception - 
[ERROR]   PwdResetControllerTest.setUp:76 NoClassDefFound mockit.MockUp

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please help.

Comment: I am confused, do you want both jmockit and jacco, from  my point of view it's a duplication. So if you prefer jacco i think you can disable jmockit code coverage as for the missing class def I suggest setting and using ${jmockit.version} to make sure versions are in sync

Comment: I am using jmockit for writing Junit test cases and using jacoco plugin for code coverage. Both have different purpose so there should not be any conflict.

Comment: Can you add a stack trace?

Comment: There are not much details in stack trace, I only get this-  [ERROR]   PwdResetControllerTest.setUp:76 NoClassDefFound mockit.MockUp

Comment: look at the surefire report files? Maybe https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/433 or https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/634

Comment: Thanks. but test cases works fine when I use maven surefire. It does not work when I use jacoco-maven-plugin. I need to use jacoco-maven-plugin so that test coverage report can be integrated with sonarqube.